# Theme ios Segment like md segment

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

Am trying to style the Segment component on ios to be like the default style of Segment on Material Design in one of my ionic2 projects.

Can any one help giving the ideal method to do it?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You just need to set the `mode` attribute like this:

```
<ion-segment mode="md" [(ngModel)]="selectedTab">
    <ion-segment-button value="segment1">
        Segment 1
    </ion-segment-button>
    <ion-segment-button value="segment2">
        Segment
    </ion-segment-button>
</ion-segment>
```

If the segment is inside a `ion-toolbar` you can set the mode **also** there so the toolbar has the height that it has on Android:

```
<ion-toolbar mode="md">
    <ion-segment mode="md" [(ngModel)]="selectedTab">
        <ion-segment-button value="segment1">
            Segment 1
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button value="segment2">
            Segment
        </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
</ion-toolbar>
```

---

**UPDATE**

As **[Zhang Bruce](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4629157/zhang-bruce)** mentioned in the comments, you have to add `mode="md"` for every segment button as well when using **Ionic 4**:

```
<ion-toolbar>
    <ion-segment mode="md" [(ngModel)]="selectedTab">
        <ion-segment-button mode="md" value="segment1">
            Segment 1
        </ion-segment-button>
        <ion-segment-button mode="md" value="segment2">
            Segment
        </ion-segment-button>
    </ion-segment>
</ion-toolbar>
```

Comment: for iOS style I change mode="ios".

Comment: note for ionic 4 you have to add mode="md" for every segment button as well, or it wont work.